# Faster alternative to extract all words in text matching words in another vector

Tags: r, stringr

I have a 300,000 row data frame with a column of text. I need to extract all words in each row that are in another vector of words.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(DateReceived = structure(c(16800, 16800, 16800, 
16800, 16800, 16800), class = "Date"), CleanText = c("deposit check account 2800 00 available balance 4300 00 spent 2500 00 2800 00 check spent xxxx 1900 00 money checking account still saved school received looked available balance xxxx called bank told check deposited fraudulent check wait seven days clear within seven days check still n clear negative balanced remained told check returned pay return fee plus negative balance want know n bank teller tcf let deposit check without telling fake tell cash check give money back put account never cleared went pay back", 
"xxxx xxxx owner xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx texas xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx texas purchased property obtaining secured deed trust citimortgage inc loan xxxx deed trust secured bank provided foreclosure sale property satisfy unpaid balance due deed trust since alleged breach agreement made monthly mortgage payments property pursuant deed trust approximately five years though eventually balance accrued bank informed intention foreclose property xxxx xxxx 2015 principal balance deed trust approximately 100000 00 bank foreclose property property sold xxxx xxxx 2015 150000 00 understanding bank received full sales price purchaser property sales price exceeded balance deed trust approximately 49000 00 bank given none 49000 00 excess proceeds sale property despite requests amount rather bank informed would provide money xxxx xxxx corporation lien property notified bank going foreclose house fact called notice sent address mine upon inquiry also found called notice sent one week prior sale property one would expected adequate time notice sent correct address foreclosure", 
"xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx nj xxxx xxxx xxxx 2015 name xxxx xxxx borrower real estate closing xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx nj xxxx closing took place xxxx xxxx 2015 closing delayed almost 2 months due bank america loan officer underwriter numerous mistakes although boa loan officer reassured penalties rescheduling closing 2800 00 fees closing never agreed see attached hud page xxxx item xxxx one informed adjusted origination charges discrepancies good faith estimates provided see attached gfe dated xxxx xxxx xxxx 1 gfe dated xxxx xxxx 2015 charge 660 00 2 75 estimated settlement charge summary dated xxxx xxxx 2015 showed rate chosen discount points 660 00 respa credit worksheet dated xxxx xxxx 2015 showed loan lock extend fee 660 00 2 gfe dated xxxx xxxx 2015 charge 1000 00 2 75 estimated settlement charge summary dated xxxx xxxx 2015 showed rate chosen discount points 1000 00 respa credit worksheet dated xxxx xxxx 2015 showed discount point fee 660 00 3 gfe dated xxxx xxxx 2015 charge 1500 00 2 75 estimated settlement charge summary dated xxxx xxxx 2015 showed rate chosen discount points 1500 00 respa credit worksheet dated xxxx xxxx 2015 showed discount point fee 1500 00 4 xxxx xxxx 2015 closing actual fee 2800 00 although boa loan officer repeatedly advised waive penalties fees paid 2800 00 closing today received refund check explanation anyone hereby demand bank america give full refund 2800 00 sincerely xxxx xxxx", 
"sears mastercard issued citibank held since 2010 paperless online statements email notification make payments online access online account statements xxxx billing cycles make payments online though receive email notification statement available talked ir customer service recently today offer solution timeline fixing problem explained result software upgrade offered send paper statement would arrive 3 days payment noted violation law insisted legal requirement send statement card holder without online access access cardholder agreement", 
"xxxx 2014 xxxx gift cards purchased home depo 500 00 total 1000 00 ended value 0 00 store told cards used california purchased always possession believe big time fraud going gift cards research says people maybe even mgmt company gets numbers back cards re inks cards innocent people like get ripped buying gifts tv news recently decided pursue year later cards locked etcc selling mgmt involved wont help purchased cards different home depot fine xxxx store commiting fraud act stupid brought attention see letter", 
"received dunning letter xxxx part debt collector attempted get validation debt sending xxxx letters receive satisfactory response sent estoppel letter see attached debt collector unbeknownst filed action xxxx xxxx xxxx courthouse acting representing bank america fraud court discovered default judgement entered xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx debt discharged wife bankruptcy 2013 evidenced credit report xxxx party debt collectors posing attorney representing bank america fact nothing interlopers purchased old debt pennies dollar attempting collect entire amount properly served sheriff required result default judgement entered"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("DateReceived", 
"CleanText"))
```

There is another vector of words called 'negative' representing the negative sentiment words. It has a total of 3500 words. Output of `head` shown here:

```
head(negative)
[1] "abandon"      "abandoned"    "abandoning"   "abandonment"  "abandonments" "abandons"
```

I need to extracted negative words pasted and returned as follows:

```
df$negativeWords
[1] "fraudulent, negative"                                    
[2] "foreclosure, unpaid, alleged, breach, foreclose, inquiry"
[3] "closing, delayed, mistakes, penalties, discrepancies"    
[4] "problem, violation"                                      
[5] "fraud"                                                   
[6] "fraud, default, bankruptcy, posing"
```

I came up with this code, which works, but is subject to `sapply` slowness. Is there a more efficient alternative that avoids looping?

```
library(stringr)
df$negativeWords <- sapply(str_extract_all(df$CleanText, '\\S+'), function(x) paste(unique(x[x %in% negative]), collapse = ', '))
```

This approach takes the following time on the full 300,000 row data frame:

```
   user  system elapsed 
 45.661   4.795  52.619
```

Answer (score 1):

after splitting it into strings, it moves from string processing into a matching/joining problem which data.table does very well

```
options(stringsAsFactors=F)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
library(rbenchmark)

#generate some sample data
numDat <- 3e3 #*100
numKey <- 35  #*100
numRep <- 30e3/numDat
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(CleanText=stri_rand_lipsum(numDat))
allwords <- unlist(unique(stri_split_regex(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", df$CleanText), "\\s+")))
negative <- sample(allwords, numKey)

#using stri_extract_all_regex and data.table
myFunc <- function() {
    strparts <- stri_extract_all_regex(df$CleanText, '\\S+')
    dt <- data.table(Key=unlist(strparts, use.names=FALSE),
                     ID=rep(1:numDat, sapply(strparts, length)),
                     key="Key")
    negDT <- data.table(Key=negative, key="Key")
    ans <<- dt[negDT][,.(negativeWords=paste(unique(Key), collapse=", ")),by="ID"][order(ID),]
}

#OP's original function
OPfunc <- function() {
    df$negativeWords <<- sapply(str_extract_all(df$CleanText, '\\S+'), function(x) paste(unique(x[x %in% negative]), collapse = ', '))
}

#benchmarking
benchmark(opfunc=OPfunc(), myfunc=myFunc(), replications=numRep)

#word sets are identical except for ordering of negative words
tail(ans)
tail(df$negativeWords)
```